# How to verify a proof prior to peer review in mathematics

Tags: publications, mathematics, independent-researcher

I think I have found that squared magic squares cannot be constructed which [is an unsolved problem](http://www.multimagie.com/English/SquaresOfSquaresSearch.htm).
I have searched for months for any mistakes and I could not find any. I have sent this to Mr.Boyer who hosts the page yet I ended up not being able to regain contact with him after he stated he found an error in my paper. However, as I think I have been aware of the error (if clarification is needed, I will do so) and have resolved the error later in the paper, I doubt that it was, in fact, an error. However, I have no method of confirming this except by myself.

Hence, I think that the only method I have left is submitting to a peer-reviewed journal. Yet is there a method of verifying the proof prior to this? I have heard that the procedure of peer review may take years.

I am only a high-school student thus I do not have any connections to mathematicians.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ask your teachers**. They know you well, probably know math better than you, and are your closest connection to the academic world. That means they're the most likely to be willing to look through your proof, capable of finding an error you didn't spot, and if they can't find anything wrong, they'll know who to approach next (e.g. their professors from when they did their degrees).

You could conceivably approach math professors at your local university directly, but you risk coming across as a crank and being ignored. If you're able to get your math teacher to vouch for your proof, that would lend strength to your claim.

Comment: Thank you! I already asked math teachers and they said they could not find any mistakes. As for people to reach next, I could not get anyone from them. I'll follow your advise and ask my teachers to vouch for me. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Universities list their faculty members, usually by faculty, then by department of a faculty. The professors, e.g. in the math department, will usually have their specialties listed along with their e-mail addresses.

Scholars don't often get serious letters from the general public about their specialty and are usually quite pleased when they do.

Comment: While probably well meant, this is terrible advice.

Comment: @YemonChoi Hi! May I ask why this is terrible advice? I am not knowledgeable in this matter at all so I just want clarification.

Comment: University faculty usually don't have time to read correspondence from people they don't know about mathematics which they don't know. There's also a big difference between "trained in area X, so could learn about problem Y if they have time" and "actively working on problem Y, so would be able to read someone's solution quickly"

Comment: @IsamuIsozaki Also – **and this is not in anyway judgement of your work** – such people get a disproportionate number of what could be termed "crank" letters, from "_I've invented perpetual motion_" downwards. _Irrespective_ of whether your proposed proof is any good or not, many, I suspect, would not look at it seriously (if at all).

Comment: @TripeHound Ah, I was a bit afraid of that. Thank you for the info!